# Is it easier to build for PhoneGap rather the Titanium?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, titanium

We are looking for a good port of our mobile web application to native app until we have the resources to build a truly native application. We have narrowed it down to PhoneGap and Titanium.

We have an HTML5 mobile version of our application. It uses things like RPC over websockets and some other JS libs. It seems as if we can just continuing using the exact same architecture if we go with PhoneGap, where as with Titanium it seems we would need to rebuild these libs and procedures to work with Titanium.

Is this true? How do these platforms differ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phonegap is your best bet here. You can put all your current code into the www directory, and then phonegap will package that into an app. Phonegap doesn't create a web app, you create the web app and let phonegap package it for you.

If you were to use Titanium you would not be able to use any of your current html or css code. If you have kept your JS logic separate from your views, then you could re-use this logic and then build new views for a titanium application but that's very time consuming.

Titanium is not a good framework, dev time is way too long due to how difficult it is to create a UI. It's also quite buggy. We developed an app in Titanium for Android and we're going to rewrite using web technologies.

It's not true that external JS libraries are difficult to use in Titanium. Everything is converted to native code.

Answer (score 2):

This [Blog](http://savagelook.com/blog/portfolio/phonegap-is-web-based-appcelerator-is-pure-javascript) has a good summary of the pros and cons of PhoneGap and Titanium Appcelerator.

Short summary: PhoneGap provides a bridge to enable standards-based web apps to access native capabilities. Appcelerator is a proprietary (non-HTML based) framework that enables the creation of native apps in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap will be much easier for you. Just port in your existing code.  Not native though.  Titanium will be a rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main difference is that PhoneGap creates a webapp written in JavaScript and Titanium creates native apps where your JavaScript code is compiled to Java or Objective-C. So you can't easily use external JavaScript libs with Titanium.